# UIViewContorller's touch event is still received even a view has added

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicontrolevents

There is a simple `UIViewController` with two buttons, every time a button is pressed, a full screen view will be added to the `viewcontorller`'s view, as its size is the same as the `viewcontroller`.

We know that if a view  is overlapped its parentview, the parentview cannot respond any event.

But if I press the `button0` and then very fast press `button1`, the view is added to the `viewcontorller` and  the second button's touch event is also evoked.

**Here is my code**:

```
@IBAction func button0Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print(#function)
        let view0 = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        view0.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        let tap0 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap0(_:)))
        view0.addGestureRecognizer(tap0)
        view.addSubview(view0)
    }

    @objc func tap0(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print(#function)
        let view = gestureRecognizer.view
        view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print(#function)
        let view1 = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap1(_:)))
        view1.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
        view.addSubview(view1)
    }


    @objc func tap1(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print(#function)
        let view = gestureRecognizer.view
        view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

**Out Put:**

`button0Pressed
button1Pressed`

So, How can I prevent the `viewcontroller`s quick touch event after the `button0` is pressed ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can try adding view.MultipleTouchEnable = false

Comment: @pooja It does not work, It's not `pressing the two buttons together` but `pressing two buttons between very short inverval`.

Comment: Can you use either buttons or gesture recognizer but not both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to have both buttons (button0 and button1) as `IBOutlet` and assign the `touchUpInside` event to fire a button0Press/button1Press function. And then you could potentially `enable` button1 `after x seconds` (1 second in my example) that button0 has been pressed. And as well viceversa.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button0Pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1Pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func button0Pressed() {
    print(#function)
    let view0 = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
    view0.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    let tap0 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap0(_:)))
    view0.addGestureRecognizer(tap0)
    view.addSubview(view0)

    // Enable button1 after 1 second
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000)) {
        self.button1.isEnabled = true
    }
}

@objc func button1Pressed() {
    print(#function)
    let view1 = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap1(_:)))
    view1.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
    view.addSubview(view1)

    // Enable button0 after 1 second
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000)) {
        self.button0.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```